# pg_dump not working - do I need to change order of $PATH?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, centos6

I'm trying to set the $PATH to pick up the latest version of pg_dump as I'm currently getting a mismatch error while doing a migrate in my Rails app (I recently changed the schema type to SQL).

I have added a new file in /etc/profile.d called pg_dump.sh, and inside that put:

```
PG_DUMP=/usr/pgsql-9.1
export PG_DUMP
PATH=$PATH:$PG_DUMP/bin
export PATH
```

On looking at echo $PATH, I get:

`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin:/root/bin`

And I still get the error.

Do I need to change the order? If so any ideas how?

---

Output of 'ls /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin':

`clusterdb   droplang  pg_archivecleanup  pg_ctl        pg_standby     psql
createdb    dropuser  pg_basebackup      pg_dump       pg_test_fsync  reindexdb
createlang  ecpg      pgbench            pg_dumpall    pg_upgrade     vacuumdb
createuser  initdb    pg_config          pg_resetxlog  postgres       vacuumlo
dropdb      oid2name  pg_controldata     pg_restore    postmaster`

And output of 'which pg_dump':

`/usr/bin/pg_dump`

---

Error message on running cap 'deploy:migrate':

```
 ** [out :: 46.4.9.199] pg_dump: server version: 9.1.4; pg_dump version: 8.4.11
 ** [out :: 46.4.9.199] pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
 ** [out :: 46.4.9.199] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 46.4.9.199] Error dumping database
```

output of 'pg_dump --version':

`pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 8.4.11`

Comment: What is the output of "ls /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin"? And  "which pg_dump"?

Comment: Hi Eric, I have added the outputs above.

Comment: Thanks does it work better if in your script you replace PATH=$PATH:$PG_DUMP/bin by PATH=$PG_DUMP/bin:$PATH? By the way what is the error message and the expected result?

Comment: Hi again Eric, I have updated the post above with the error message. I am using Capistrano, and running cap deploy:migrate on my local machine which runs rake db:migrate on the production server. I'm not sure I can change the script to use a different path (?) Btw, when I try $pg_dump --version, I get: pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 8.4.11 - which makes me think I just need to get the new path before the old one in $PATH?

Comment: Short answer : Yes. But there might exist some cleaner solutions.

Comment: Thanks Eric ...would you know how I could do that? Any ideas what would normally happen in this situation?

Comment: I did it! just changed the path in the file to: PATH=$PG_DUMP/bin:$PATH and now it works! Do you wanna write up a quick answer then I can mark it as accepted answer? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to edit /etc/profile.d/pg_dump.sh :

```
PG_DUMP=/usr/pgsql-9.1
export PG_DUMP
PATH=$PG_DUMP/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: You should also consider figuring out (a) WHY you have multiple Postgres versions (or at least clients) installed, and (b) if you need them (If you don't need them, get rid of the older ones -- 9.x clients should be fine talking to 8.x databases, though obviously you should test this in your environment before making any irreversible changes)

Comment: That's a good point - Though I think from memory, I had to keep the original postgres as webmin needs it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this answer that explains how to [symlink the new version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635435/2-versions-of-pg-dump-on-my-osx-lion). (reprinting below for convenience):

your new version of pg_dump is not in your PATH, all you need to do is to remove the old version, and symlink the new one to any directory in your PATH, for example, /usr/bin.

Like follows:

```
sudo ln -s /actual/new/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump
```

To find the new pg_dump, you need to know the location of the postgresql install.  If you used homebrew, it's /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.2/bin (or whatever your version is)